# DataRoutines not creating data in Access Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, ms-access

today, I am trying to use DataRoutines to insert some values into my Access Database. However, it did not work as well as there were no records created. Does anyone know what's wrong with my code?

This is my DataRoutines (dataroutines2) file

```
 public void CreateRecs(string strUserId)
{
    OleDbConnection mDB = new OleDbConnection();
    mDB.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source="
        + Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/webBase.accdb");
    OleDbCommand cmd; OleDbDataReader rdr;
    string strSql;
    string strOFlag = "F";
    // check to see if there is an active order record
    strSql = "SELECT eStatus FROM enrolInfo WHERE eUserId = @UserId "
       + "ORDER BY eEnrolNo DESC;";
    cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSql, mDB);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", OleDbType.Char).Value = strUserId;
    mDB.Open();
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    Boolean booRows = rdr.HasRows;
    if (booRows) //when booRows is true, there are order records for the user
    {
        rdr.Read();
        if ((string)rdr["eStatus"] != "Ordering") //status of an active order is "Ordering"
        {
            strOFlag = "M"; //"T" means there is a need to create a new Orders record
        }
        else { strOFlag = "M"; }
        mDB.Close();
        if (strOFlag == "M")
        {
            //insert a new order record
            string strStatus = "Ordering";
            strSql = "INSERT INTO enrolInfo (eUserId, eStatus) VALUES (@UserId, @Status)";
            cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSql, mDB);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", strUserId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", strStatus);
            mDB.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            mDB.Close();
        }

        //get back order No - this order no is needed when the user buys an item
        strSql = "SELECT eEnrolNo FROM enrolInfo WHERE eUserId = @UserId "
            + "ORDER BY eEnrolNo DESC;";
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSql, mDB);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", OleDbType.Char).Value = strUserId;
        mDB.Open();
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        rdr.Read();
        Session["tOrderNo"] = rdr["eEnrolNo"]; //store the active order no in the sOrderNo
        mDB.Close();
        return;

    }
}
```

This is the code that will route the solution to the DataRoutines file in my Register Page

```
               //prepare Session variables for newly register customer
            Session["sFlag"] = "M";
            Session["tUserId"] = (string)txtUserId.Text;
            Session["tName"] = (string)txtName.Text;
            Session["tAddress"] = (string)txtAddress.Text;
            Session["tTel"] = (string)txtTel.Text;
            Session["tEmail"] = (string)txtEmail.Text;
            String strUserId = (string)Session["tUserId"];
            DataRoutines2 DRObject = new DataRoutines2();
            DRObject.CreateRecs(strUserId);
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is this C#, ASP.NET? What is a DataRoutine and do you receive any error messages?

Comment: Yes this is C# & ASP.NET. Dataroutine is the file which I named so that the page can refer to to add the information back into my Access Database. And No, there was no error messages.

Comment: Put some kind of output or message in this block `if (strOFlag == "M")` to check whether it ever enters this block, or use a Breakpoint.